# Is it possible to use more than 1 event in a discord bot. (my own discord bot made in python)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that react on 4 different event. but the last event will stop the above event from working. does anyone know how to fix this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from asyncio import sleep as s 
import re




client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("RickGrBot Is Connected With Discord")


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

@client.command()
async def hallo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hallo!")

    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    url_pattern = re.compile(r'https?://tenor.com/view/im-so-drunk-i-barely-can-see-gif-18529125')
    if url_pattern.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("Gijs.")
                      
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    url_pattern = re.compile(r'https?://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1042805105658953808/1089794665001263114/Screenshot_2023-01-01-23-12-25-177_com.android.chrome.png')
    if url_pattern.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("Brandon.")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    url_pattern = re.compile(r'https?://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1042805105658953808/1089802868946636831/Screenshot_2022-10-24-18-06-13-64_1c337646f29875672b5a61192b9010f9.jpg')
    if url_pattern.search(message.content):
    channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
    await channel.send("dylan.")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
url_pattern = re.compile(r'https?://tenor.com/view/angry-little-girl-annoyed-cute-gif-22673877')
if url_pattern.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("Rick.")
client.run("MY_TOKEN")
```

i have add the await client.process_commands(message) but this only works for my client commands and not for my events.

Comment: Use just one `on_message` event and put all the `if` conditions inside it

Comment: 1. Just combine it into one. 2. If you really want to, you can't have multiple methods with the same name in Python, name them something else. Then you can use a listener to listen to the `on_message` event in a function with a different name.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `client.get_channel` then sending instead of just using `message.channel.send()`?

Answer (score 1):

The repetition of `on_message` might be your issue. Could you try the following code, I just restructured with if/else conditions:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from asyncio import sleep as s 
import re

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("RickGrBot Is Connected With Discord")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

@client.command()
async def hallo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hallo!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    url_pattern1 = re.compile(r'https?://tenor.com/view/im-so-drunk-i-barely-can-see-gif-18529125')
    url_pattern2 = re.compile(r'https?://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1042805105658953808/1089794665001263114/Screenshot_2023-01-01-23-12-25-177_com.android.chrome.png')
    url_pattern3 = re.compile(r'https?://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1042805105658953808/1089802868946636831/Screenshot_2022-10-24-18-06-13-64_1c337646f29875672b5a61192b9010f9.jpg')
    url_pattern4 = re.compile(r'https?://tenor.com/view/angry-little-girl-annoyed-cute-gif-22673877')
    
    if url_pattern1.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("Gijs.")
    
    elif url_pattern2.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("Brandon.")
    
    elif url_pattern3.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("dylan.")
    
    elif url_pattern4.search(message.content):
        channel = client.get_channel(1089903003739361312)
        await channel.send("Rick.")

client.run("MY_TOKEN")
```